# Compute Volume of revolution

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the region bounded by the curves $$y=x , 2y=x+4$$ about x-axis
I used the washer method as 
$$v=\pi\int_0^4\left[(\frac{x}{2}+2)^2-x^2\right]dx=16\pi$$
Then
I used the shell method as 
$$v=2\pi\int_0^4y^2dy-2\pi\int_2^4y(2y-4)dy$$
But i got different result than than the with the washer method , where is the mistake

Comment: revolution about which axis?

Comment: x-axis @daulomb

Comment: @Hussein: I added the answer

Answer (score 0):

Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the region bounded by the curves $$y=x , 2y=x+4.$$
I used the washer method as 
$$v=\pi\int_0^4\left[(\frac{x}{2}+2)^2-x^2\right]dx=16\pi.$$
It seems you revolve the region about the $x$-axis. But your calculation is missing. Because you didnt consider the case for $-4\leq x\leq 0$. 
You also have to calculate the volume $$\pi\int_{-4}^0\left[(\frac{x}{2}+2)^2\right]dx.$$

Note: if you sketch the region you will understand what I mean.

Edit: OP said that the region is in the first quadrant, so I edit according to this. The volume generated by revolving the region about the $x$ axis is:
$$v=\pi\int_0^4\left[(\frac{x}{2}+2)^2-x^2\right]dx=16\pi.$$

If you use shell method the region is divided into two parts:$$V=\int_0^22\pi y^2dy+\int_2^42\pi y(-y+4)dy=\int_0^22\pi y^2dy+2\pi\int_2^4(-y^2+4y)dy=16\pi.$$

Comment: The question is given with a graph in the first quadrants so we neglect the negative part of x-axis@daulomb

Comment: Hımm so I will edit according to this

Comment: @Hussein Mohmed: it is now okey you can check

Comment: Thank you , but i did not understand what the mistake in my solution i divided the region into a greater region that included by $$y=x$$ from 0 to 4 , then i eleminated the smaller part included by the $$2y=x+4$$ i think i must get the same result as the case of addig the two region you did

Comment: @Hussien Mohamed: if you look the picture you see that the lower and upper lmits of $x$ in terms of $y$ are different. This occurs at $y=2$.

Comment: when $0\leq y\leq 2$, $0\leq x\leq y$; but when $2\leq y\leq 4$, $2y-4\leq x\leq y$.

Comment: I think the second integranfld in your solution should be $$[y-(2y+4)] =y(-y-4)$$ Is it right or i missed something ?@daulomb

Comment: $2y=x+4\rightarrow x=2y-4$ and $y\big(y-(2y-4)\big)=y(-y+4)$.